# Chrome extensions with text files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am new to chrome extension and i need to develop a chrome extension which can handle text/json files (should be able to perform read-write operations).Files will be stored at the same machine(path may be D:/abc/xyz.text) where i will install chrome extension.Does any one have any idea?

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where you can get help with your errors, but it isn't a place about "give me some code about how to do x".

Answer (score 2):

That would sadly be not easy or downright impossible - a Chrome Extension cannot get read/write permissions for the real filesystem.

A Chrome App on the other hand can, using [`chrome.fileSystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem).

Your options:

1. Make a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/) instead. Might not be possible if you need browser integration.
2. Make an extension and a Chrome App that [talk to each other](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external), letting the Chrome App handle the file operations. Complicated install, but maximum flexibility.
3. Make an extension that uses a [Native Host module](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to do operations with the filesystem. It will be even more complicated install, but *UNLIMITED POWER*.
4. Make an extension that works with [its own virtual filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/); if the user needs a file, you can use [`chrome.downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) to export it.
5. Make an extension that works with some sort of cloud storage solution, e.g. with files in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation).