# Chrome extension to store the keys users press

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension which will store all the keys pressed by the user and will store those keys into a text file inside the directory.

I want to keep track of user key pressed whatever he searches or types i want to store it into a text file ..

For now I've made it store the keywords in an array and alert it when needed. The array isn't getting alerted.

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
var your_array = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        var keyPress;

        if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
            keyPress = event.keyCode;
        } else if (e) {
            keyPress = e.which;
        }

        your_array.push(String.fromCharCode(keyPress));

        return false; // Prevents the default action
    };

    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(your_array);
        die;
    }, false);

}, false);
```

...and this is what my HTML file looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Storing Keyword</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='popup.css' />
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>I can store your keywords</h3>
        <button id="checkPage">Really Show Me !</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JSON manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Keyword store",
    "description": "This extension will analyze a page using GTmetrix",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "avator/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

The issue is that the alert appears but it gets closed automatically within few milliseconds.

If anyone has any idea how to store keys in a text file please let me know about that too...

Thank you.

Comment: you want to keep track of clicks on page of the site? or your page popup?

Comment: @UserName I want to keep track of user key pressed whatever he searches or types i want to store it into a text file ..

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that the alert appears but it gets closed automatically within few milliseconds.

Chrome popups do not survive focus loss.

Your `alert()` cause the dialog box to appear, which loses focus and the page closed/destroyed.

Use `console.log` and [inspect the popup for debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) instead.

> If anyone has any idea how to store keys in a text file please let me know about that too

There was a recent question where I [answered rather extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37342661/934239) about options to do it. If you need persistent storage, use `chrome.storage` API. If you need to specifically output a file, you can't get R/W access from an extension, though you can offer a file for "download".

> I want to keep track of user key pressed whatever he searches or types

That's not going to be possible; your extension as it is now will only get notified about keystrokes within your popup. There isn't an extension API to globally intercept keypresses. At most, you can inject similar scripts in all tabs, but again this will not get you stuff typed in the address/search bar.