# Read content of a local file with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, kango-framework

I am developing an extension for the chrome browser.  I use the KangoExtensions framework. The extension is written in JavaScript. I want to read the content of a file, which is located on the local filesystem. What is the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: `local file system` is like a ```d:\``` folder or my home directory on linux? Nah, an extension can't see them. You can only have a standard HTML file-upload button or drag'n'drop support. See also [Chrome extensions with text files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343166)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extensions with text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342661/chrome-extensions-with-text-files)

Answer (score 8):

If you already know the file's path in the filesystem you just need to add a permission to `file://*`in your manifest file and make a GET XMLHttpRequest to the url `file://{filepath}`.